# How to convert array to string in python?

Tags: python

i have array like below

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

how can i convert it to `'1,2,3'` using python

i have a  usecase where i want to add a filter parameter to url like below

```
url = some_url?id__in=1,2,3
```

i was initially thinking to pass it like so

```
url = some_url?id__in={arr}
```

but this is incorrect. i am new to python and i have browsed how to do this.

```
" ".join(str(x) for x in arr)
```

but this will give output `'1 2 3'`

how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Use ``",".join(str(x) for x in arr)`` instead of ``" ".join(str(x) for x in arr)``.

Comment: You are just missing comma (,) in your code. Use  `",".join(str(x) for x in a)`

Comment: What module are you using for performing request? Is it [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)? Common way to send list is `?id__in=1&id__in=2&id__in=3"` not `id__in=1,2,3"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This gives you the `1,2,3` that you asked for.

`",".join(str(x) for x in arr)`

Answer (score 3):

Try the below

```
arr = [1,2,3]
string = ','.join(str(x) for x in arr)
print(string)
```

output

```
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join on the `,` character instead of a space:

```py
",".join(str(x) for x in arr)
```